# Remove 1 of 3 map overlays

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I have an app that displays points on a map. There are 3 map overlays (1) for the current user; (2) for the user's friends/contacts; (3) for other people. I am trying to allow the use to select what is displayed on the map. The goal is to allow them to display everyone (user, friends and others) or to filter the map to display just their friends/contacts.

I can add the different overlays to the map just fine. The problem is removing the overlays.

I tried the approach here -- [How to refresh an activity? Map View refresh fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756409/how-to-refresh-an-activity-map-view-refresh-fails) -- which suggests to remove items by index using the following code:

```
private void showFriends(){

mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
int j = othersMapOverlay.size();
for(int i = friendsMapOverlay.size; i < j; i++){
    mapOverlays.remove(i);
}
mapView.invalidate();
}
```

My strategy here was to create a list of all overlays - mapOverlays and then, using the for loop, start from the end of the first overlay, friendsMapOverlay, and remove until I reached the end of the second map overlay, othersMapOverlay.

That didn't work.

I also tried to remove the list object using both

```
mapOverlays.remove(othersMapOverlay);
```

or

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(othersMapOverlay);
```

but neither of these does the trick. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following. Its not really hiding or removing an overlay just clearing and redrawing. This has to be less efficient than what I want to do - i.e. just remove what's there but it works. . . for now.

```
private void showEveryone(){

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mapOverlays.clear();
    mapView.invalidate();
    JSONArray friends = buildFriendList();
    JSONArray others = buildOthersList();
    getUserDataForMap(friends, "friends");
    getUserDataForMap(others, "others");

}
```